# Installing Teradata in Debian or CentOS

Tags: database, centos, debian, teradata

Does anyone knows how to install Teradata in Debian or CentOS?

I wanted to give Teradata a try but I can't really find a download installer and/or clear instructions anywhere to install it.

If **Plan A** doesn't work (it's not simple, or even possible to install it) I was wondering if any of the following alternatives would work (and are really useful for basic usage):

- **Plan B:** I saw a downloadable VMWare image somewhere that I could try to use.
- **Plan C:** I think I saw an AWS (Amazon Web Services) offer time ago.

If you had done it can you point me to the right path? Otherwise, if you have tried any of the alternatives, did it work well?

**Note:** This is not for a production installation, but more as a learning experience, and to study this database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teradata runs on Suse SLES 11 only. The easiest (and recommended) way to get it on any other OS is to use the virtual edition on VMWare (Player):

[Teradata Express](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/database/teradata-express-for-vmware-player%20Teradata%20Express)

You need to register to be able to download.

Comment: I guess it was wishful thinking to install on a free OS (Suse requires a license). I guess the VMWare option is the simplest.

Comment: @TheImpaler: Even if you got a SLES license you would still need the Teradata packages, which are not freely available :-)

Comment: Our you could use AWS, depending on your experience.